# Any STUN/TURN/ICE client library in PHP?

Tags: php, nat, stun, turn

I am trying to establish P2P between two PHP daemon deployed on machines in different network (both behind NAT). I searched around for NAT traversal using PHP on Google and seems like their is no existing solution for this in PHP.

Does anyone know about a solution/library to work this around with PHP?

Comment: [This guy](http://thomas.gelf.net/blog/archives/STUN-Client-mit-PHP,30.html) (site in german) has built a [PHP STUN client](http://websvn.gelf.net/browse.php?rt=phpstunclient&f=trunk/Stun/) - maybe worth checking out, it doesn't look like an actively maintained project though

Comment: cool seems to be a good enough starting point if i go on and do it all out in PHP.... probably can extend on the work by this guy... Thanks Pekka

Comment: man have you completed your search...it would be helpful if you show some way to achieve it thanks...

Answer (score 3):

If anybody else is looking for an answer, here is a simple class that does the job:

```php
<?php

class STUNClient
{
    private $socket;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //stun.l.google.com
        $this->setServerAddr("66.102.1.127", 19302);
        $this->createSocket();
    }

    public function setServerAddr($host, $port = 3478)
    {
        $this->serverIP   = $host;
        $this->serverPort = $port;
    }

    public function createSocket()
    {
        $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, getprotobyname("udp"));
        socket_set_nonblock($this->socket);
    }

    public function getPublicIp()
    {
        $msg = "\x00\x01\x00\x08\xc0\x0c\xee\x42\x7c\x20\x25\xa3\x3f\x0f\xa1\x7f\xfd\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00";

        $numberOfBytesSent = socket_sendto($this->socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $this->serverIP, $this->serverPort);

        $st = time();
        while (time() - $st < 1) {

            socket_recvfrom($this->socket, $data, 32, 0, $remoteIP, $remotePort);

            if (strlen($data) < 32) {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        try {

            $info = unpack("nport/C4s", substr($data, 26, 6));
            $ip   = sprintf("%u.%u.%u.%u", $info["s1"], $info["s2"], $info["s3"], $info["s4"]);
            $port = $info['port'];
            return [
                'ip'   => $ip,
                'port' => $port
            ];
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return [
                'ip'   => "0.0.0.0",
                'port' => "0"
            ];
        }

    }

}
```

It's used like this:

```php
$sc  = new STUNClient;
print_r( $sc->getPublicIp() ); //prnints out the public ip and port
```

Comment: I am scared about this msg starting with null-terminating character. Does strlen returns 0 for it? On my computer it returns 28, but what means these characters in string? Any documentation, please.

Comment: from rfc8489,"As such, the transaction ID MUST be uniformly
   and randomly chosen from the interval 0 .. 2**96-1 and MUST be
   cryptographically random." are you sure you want to hardcode the transaction id?